# Contractible dense subset

Tags: general-topology

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a proper closed connected subset and $U\subset X$ a dense and connected open proper subset. Is $U$ automatically contractible? If not can you provide me of some counterexamples?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $U$ be $X - \{0\}$. Then $U$ is dense, connected, open, and proper in $X$, but is not contractible.

Comment: You meant U is dense in the closure of X, right? Since he wanted a closed subset

Comment: Edited to add that I mean $X$ to be the closed unit disk.